# Weird limit problem

Tags: limits

I cam across this unusual problem in a textbook and have no clue how to solve it, so any help would  be appreciated.
Find the value of the limit

$$\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\cos^{2m}(n! \cdot \pi \cdot x)$$ where $x$ is irrational.

Comment: I edited the math to show it more clearly.

Comment: Hint: You get different results depending on which of m and n goes to infinity first.

Comment: Is m an integer.

Answer (score 1):

One answer:
For fixed $n$,
since $n!\pi x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$,
$|\cos(n!\pi x)| < 1$
so
$\lim_{m \to \infty} \cos^{2m}(n!\pi x)
= 0
$.

The other case,
for fixed $m$
finding
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^{2m}(n!\pi x)
$
is harder.

Comment: I didn't understand your point where you are telling m to be fixed but as in the question it tends to infinity.

Comment: @user291957: If the limit as $n$ and $m$ tend to infinity independent of each exists, then the iterated limits must exist and be equal. To calculate an iterated limit, first take fix one variable (either $m$ or $n$), and take the limit as the other variable tends to infinity.

Comment: What if the given limit expression is not the interchangeable with iterated limit form @Clayton . Can you elaborate when can a limit of two variables be interchanges with iterated variables. Any detailed explanation or link would be definitely appreciated.